# Generate a PDF file then save that file locally to verify it contains the data i'm expecting it to

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, node-streams

I'm trying to generate a PDF file and ultimately I'm going to be sending it as a base64 encoded string in an HTTP call, but for now i just want to save to a file so I can verify the contents.

With the code below, i'm getting a pdf file called `consentTest.pdf` but when i open it with a pdf viewer there is nothing in the file.

I know the PDF is being generated correctly b/c when I uncomment the line `doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('consent1.pdf'))` right after PDF generation it saves it with the expected contents when I open it in a PDF viewer.

```
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit')

/**
 * Creates a pdf consent form to be sent as a base64encoded string
 */
function createPdfConsent() {
  let doc = new PDFDocument()
  writeContent(doc)
  // doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('consent1.pdf')) <-- THIS SUCCESSFULLY SAVES THE FILE WITH THE EXPECTED CONTENTS
  let file
  // Add every chunk to file
  doc.on('data', chunk => {
    if (file === undefined) {
      file = chunk
    } else {
      file += chunk
    }
  })

  // On complete, print the base64 encoded string, but also save to a file so we can verify it's contents
  doc.on('end', () => {
    const encodedFile = new Buffer(file)
    console.log('encodedFile = ', encodedFile.toString('base64'))

    // Testing printing the file back out from base64 encoding
    fs.writeFile('consentTest.pdf', encodedFile, err => {
      console.log('err = ', err)
    })
  })

  doc.end()
}

/************ Private *************

/**
 * Writes the consent content to the pdf
 * @param  {Object} doc The pdf document that we want to write to
 * @private
 */
function writeContent(doc) {
  doc.fontSize(16).text('This is the consent form', 50, 350)
}

module.exports = {
  createPdfConsent
}
```

Comment: Note you do `file += chunk` but you never gave `file` a value first. So it is going to try to concatenate to an `undefined` value and cause you to have a corrupted value, ie you will end up with something like `undefinedPDFDATA`. Try opening up your file in a text editor or hex editor you should see something to that effect

Comment: Good call. Updated. Same issue though.

Comment: Does your outputted file have any actual contents? If so are they in the proper format, ie if you open it in a hex editor do you see a proper PDF header(signature). What happens if you directly use `file` with `writeFile()`

Comment: This is the contents. Not sure what i'm looking for https://gist.github.com/toymachiner62/8519ace73a48dccd079f5ed4d98a79c8

Answer (score 0):

Seems I was incorrectly handling/using chunks.

replacing:

```
 ...
 let file
  // Add every chunk to file
  doc.on('data', chunk => {
    if (file === undefined) {
      file = chunk
    } else {
      file += chunk
    }
  })

  // On complete, print the base64 encoded string, but also save to a file so we can verify it's contents
  doc.on('end', () => {
    const encodedFile = new Buffer(file)
  ...
```

with:

```
...
 let file = []
  // Add every chunk to file
  doc.on('data', chunk => {
    file.push(chunk)
  })

  doc.on('end', () => {
    const encodedFile = Buffer.concat(file)
  ...
```

was the magic ticker